# JQuery Masked Input Does Not Working in Rails 6

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, maskedinput, embedded-ruby

I am trying to use the JQuery Masked Input in my form on Rails 6. But it seems to me that the **application.js** in assets is not working, i am not sure. I installed the plugin through yarn with the command: `yarn add jquery-mask-plugin`. It was included in **package.json** as a dependency.

To setup, I went to **app/assets/javascripts/application.js**. This is the file:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-mask-plugin
//= require_tree .

$.jMaskGlobals.watchDataMask = true;
```

In **app/javascript/packs/application.js** I tried to import the JQuery and the plugin ass well:

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
require("jquery")
import 'inputmask';
```

Now in my form, this is how I tried to use the plugin:

```
<%= form.text_field :cpf, class:'form-control', 'data-mask': '999.999.999-99' %>
```

As I said before, I am not sure, but I think the problem is the **application.js** file in assets, cause I wrote a `console.log("test")` command just to see if it is executing and nothing appeared at the web console when the server was running.

Can someone would help me?

Comment: try `$('.your-class-for-input').mask('999.999.999-99' )` in the console

Comment: Have you solved the problem? Can you share the way?

Answer (score 2):

1. yarn add "jquery-mask-plugin"
2. in app/javascript/packs/application.js

add require

```
require("jquery-mask-plugin")
```

3. in app/javascript/packs/application.js

add line at the buttom

```
$.jMaskGlobals.watchDataMask = true;
```

4. in .html.erb

   = d.text_field :phone_number, autocomplete: "phone Number", class: "form-control", placeholder: "03xx-xxxxxxx" , 'data-mask': '0000-0000000'

**or**
in html.erb

```
<%= d.text_field :phone_number, autocomplete: "phone Number", class: "form-control", placeholder: "03xx-xxxxxxx" , 'data-mask': '0000-0000000' %>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. in `app/javascript/packs/application.js`

   ```
   $(document).on('turbolinks:load', function () {
     var im = new Inputmask('999.999.999-99');
     var selector = $('#person_document');
     im.mask(selector);
   });
   ```
2. `yarn add inputmask`
3. in `app/javascript/packs/application.js`

   ```
   require('inputmask');
   ```
4. in `assets/javascript/application.js`

   ```
   //= require jquery 
   //= require jquery_ujs 
   //= require jquery-mask-plugin 
   //= require_tree .  
   //= require jquery.inputmask.bundle.min
   $.jMaskGlobals.watchDataMask = true;
   ```
5. in `app/javascript/packs/application.js`

   ```
   require('inputmask');
   ```

This solved the problem for me.